# NodeJS Pdfmake how to add an image

Tags: node.js, express, pdfmake

I'm using the api pdfmake in nodeJS to generate pdf files http://pdfmake.org/#/ but i do not not know how to add image to the document and always i get below error

```
error invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)
```

This is how i add the image  and it exist in the same folder of the code:

```
body: [
    [{ rowSpan: 2, image: 'data:aa/png' }, 'Capteur', '', 'image', 'image', 'image'],
    ['', 'Health', '', 'Proximite', 'Lumiere', 'Geroscope'],
]
```

I need some helps and thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you're not specifing a valid `base64`-encoded string.
You need to change it to a correct base64-encoded string (note that you can use e.g. [this website](https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64) to convert your `png` to a `base64`-encoded string or you let node do the conversion as they did [in this issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1085)):

```
const pdfDefinition = {
    content: [          
        { rowSpan: 2, image:'data:image/png;base64,<put-your-base64-string-here>'}          
    ]       
}
```

Also note that only JPEG and PNG images are supported currently.